# How to get public key from cert-manager?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, cert-manager

I need to get a public key from cert manager from bash. How to do it properly?

I can see the private key in kubernetes secrets; how to get public key that can be safely shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways, all should return the same output. If they are not, something is wrong.

All of this assumes Unix-y shell, and jq, base64, openssl installed. The secret is in `cert-certname`, the website (assuming this protects a website) is at https://example.com

1.

```
kubectl get secret cert-certname -o json  | jq -r '.data."tls.crt"' | base64 -d > tls.crt
openssl x509 -inform pem -in tls.crt -pubkey -noout
```

2. 

```
kubectl get secret cert-certname -o json  | jq -r '.data."tls.key"' | base64 -d > tls.key
openssl rsa -in tls.key -pubout
```

3. 

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

Note that 1) and 2) creates files containing secrets on your disk; you should delete them afterwards. And never ever put them to git or similar version control.